# Why does the unknown author of Hebrews attribute authorship of Psalm 95 to David, but in my bible it is not written that the author of it is David?

Tags: hebrews, david, psalms, apocrypha, deuterocanonical-books

I wonder why does the unknown author of Hebrews attribute authorship of Psalm 95 to David, but in my bible it is not written that the author of it is David? Was it an error from the unknown author of Hebrews or an error from the spirit which inspired him or not an error at all?

> Hebrews 4:7
>
> Again, he limiteth a certain day, saying in **David**, **To day, after so
> long a time; as it is said, To day if ye will hear his voice, harden
> not your hearts**.
>
> Psalm 95:7-8
>
> For he is our God; and we are the people of his pasture,
> and the sheep of his hand. **To day if ye will hear his voice, Harden
> not your heart**, as in the provocation, and as in the day of
> temptation in the wilderness:

Comment: oh, I missed it. Thank you

Comment: It would help if it named the specific version rather than "my bible".

Answer (score 1):

It was no one's error. The author of Hebrews was quoting from the Septuagint (LXX) and your bible must be translated from the Masoretic Text.

That is the translation from Greek (LXX):

*1 **[The praise of a Song by David.]** Come, let us exult in the Lord; let us make a joyful noise to God our Saviour.
2 Let us come before his presence with thanksgiving, and make a joyful noise to him with psalms.
3 For the Lord is a great God, and a great king over all gods: for the Lord will not cast off his people.
4 For the ends of the earth are in his hands; and the heights of the mountains are his.
5 For the sea is his, and he made it: and his hands formed the dry land.
6 Come, let us worship and fall down before him; and weep before the Lord that made us.
7 For he is our God; and we are the people of his pasture, and the sheep of his hand.
8 To-day, if ye will hear his voice, harden not your hearts, as in the provocation, according to the day of irritation in the wilderness:
9 where your fathers tempted me, proved me, and saw my works.
10 Forty years was I grieved with this generation, and said, They do always err in their heart, and they have not known my ways.
11 So I sware in my wrath, They shall not enter into my rest.*
https://www.ellopos.net/elpenor/greek-texts/septuagint/chapter.asp?book=24&page=94

Comment: + 1   So then the question becomes "why did the LXX this it was a psalm of David but the Masoretic did not?"

Comment: "The LXX headings contain everything in theri MT counterparts, except the לדוד ascriptions in Psalms 122 and 124. LXX sometimes supplements MT headings: 13 LXX psalms have Davidic ascriptions absent in MT and 22 of the 24 psalms that have no heading in MT gain one in LXX, leaving only 1 and 2 untitled. (…) Whether LXX is an expansion, or MT a contraction, of an earlier Vorlage is unclear."

Comment: topic for another question?